# Access htaccess Rewritten URL without query parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have rewritten a PHP file's URL as:

```
RewriteRule ^psu/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) _psu.php?id=$1&mb=$2&cpu=$3&name=$4 [L]
```

This makes the page _psu.php accessible only as:

```
psu/path/path/path/path
```

Any other URLs like:

```
psu/path/path/path/
psu/path/path/
psu/path/
psu
```

gives 404 Not Found Error.
How can I rewrite the URL - `psu/path/path/path/path` keeping the above URL accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^psu(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)/?)?)?)?)?$ _psu.php?id=$1&mb=$2&cpu=$3&name=$4 [L]
```

In `_psu.php`

```
<?
$id = $_GET["id"];
$mb = $_GET["mb"];
$cpu = $_GET["cpu"];
$name = $_GET["name"];

echo "id: $id<br>
mb: $mb<br>
cpu: $cpu<br>
name: $name";
?>
```

Check Accessible URLs:

```
/psu/1/2/3/4
/psu/1/2/3
/psu/1/2
/psu/1
/psu
```

Satisfies all mentioned retirements.

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic length path after `psu` use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
AcceptPathInfo on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^psu(/.*)?$ _psu.php$1 [L,NC]
```

In inside `php` code of `_psu.php` use:

```
$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]
```

to get path info. You can split it by `/` to get list of path components.

Comment: I didn't even try it. This is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Clarify what's wrong with it? It matches all the URLs you have shown in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^psu(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)/?)?)?)?)?$ _psu.php?id=$1&mb=$2&cpu=$3&name=$4 [L]
```

Comment: May not work correctly for a path like `psu/path/path/path`. $3 will become blank and $4 will have final path match

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank's I changed my rule with that